# Jackson Polymorphic Lists of Specific types

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I am trying to use Jackson to deserialize the folloing JSON.

```
{
    "zooName":"Test Zoo Park",
    "animalExhibits" : {
        "lions" : [
            {
                "gender" : "male",
                "name" : "simba"
            },
            {
                "gender" : "female",
                "name" : "lady"
            }
        ],
        "penguins" : [
            {
                "type":"zipper"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

animalExhibits is a map. The value of the pair is an interface so I can keep adding animals to my exhibits. The lists extend the interface. But the specific list will always contain the same object (no inner polymorphism).

I want to be able to deserialize based on the field name. I.e. "lions" and "penguins" and more as my zoo grows.

I am unsure if a custom TypeIdResolver is the way to go. The Enum's the Jackson exposes for JsonTypeInfo do not seem to cut it for me at first glance.

Comment: Why can't you have `AnimalExhibits` class with `List<Lion> lions` etc? `Map` is really not ideal for this kind of structure,

Comment: AnimalExhibits is a map, not a defined object. I don't want to continuously update. But what you bring up is helpful. I wish Jackson could just look at the key in the map to decide how to deserialize it